# XML Signing in PKCS#7 format

Tags: xml, java

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что значит подписать xml  в формате PKCS#7? Влияет ли это формат на состав тегов xml? Или только на алгоритмы генерации ключей, состава сертификатов?
Какие библиотеки (Java) удобно использовать для реализации цифровой подписи xml документа?

Answer (score 1):

Для подписи документов в формате PKCS#7 подойдет библиотека [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html). Насколько я знаю, цифровая подпись не модифицирует исходный документ, а добавляется к нему. То есть дополнительно к XML документу будет еще и подпись формата PKCS#7, например, в виде строки base64.

Comment: То, что добаляется это я знаю.. Но там есть определенный набор тэгов для подписи xml файлов, я говорил про них.. 
Вы писали "То есть дополнительно к XML документу будет еще и подпись формата PKCS#7". Вот мне очень хотелось бы узнать, что же это за формат такой и на что он влияет.
Все равно спасибо за ответ.

Comment: По-моему, это скорее относится к [XML Signature](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-o-Simple), а не к PKCS#7.